# Rails association "parent" reference in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My following question might indicate a lack of proper understanding to how things really work in Ruby, Rails, or even general oOP concepts, and believe me i thought and searched a lot before asking, but i couldn't even form the correct search query to find the proper answer, so anyways here is what I would like to achieve ...

```
song = Artist.first.albums.first.songs.first
```

this -to my understanding- will call the songs model and pass Artist model and Album model reference to the Song model to form an SQL query to fetch the data from the DB -since i am using ActiveRecord.

The real question; is there a way to know which Artist and Album called the Song model? this is useful specially in many-to-many relations where i don't want to pass an extra reference for the album/artist.

So if I have a function in my model for whatever reason it will be able to tell who created this Song instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's too much chaining and it's overcomplicating things.

However, you could do `song.artist` or `song.album` to retrieve the song's Artist and Album, supposing you have the `belongs_to :album` and `belongs_to :artist` relationships declared in your Song model.

However, you could simply do:

```
artist = Artist.first
album = artist.albums.first
songs = album.songs
```

This way you have the Artist, his/her album you want (in this case the first one) and its songs all on different variables and you can handle them separately.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am well aware of how ugly the chaining is, I used it as an example, to avoid exactly what was done, which is having to pass two or three variables to a view, for so many reasons, anyways as i was looking i found a wonderful module in Ruby 's stdlib, i'm not sure though of the side effects so i'll do more reading on it, it's called ObjectSpace, and i think it's easy to achieve what i wanted using ObjectSpace.each_object(Artist).

edit: i will be calling ObjectSpace in a class method obviously and not the view.

Comment: I've edited my initial post. Doesn't it answer your question now?